# Intersecting Polygon in R, importing polygon for Spatial Clustering Analysis in Spatstat

Tags: r, geospatial

I am trying to import a polygon into R using the `readShapePoly` command and turn the polygon in to a border using `as(filename,"owin")`. I keep getting the response that the polygon contains duplicate vertices and self-intersecting polygons:

```
Polygon 1 contains duplicated vertices
Polygon 1 is self-intersecting
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.
done.
Polygon 1 contains duplicated vertices
Polygon 1 is self-intersecting
Checking for cross-intersection between 10 polygons...1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.
done.
Error in owin(poly = opls) : 
  Polygon data contain duplicated vertices and self-intersection
```

I tried cleaning up the polygon with the Repair Geometry function in ArcGIS but it didn't help. What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: you can fix most of these kinds of problems in an automated way with a zero-width buffer. Use at your own risk, there's no way of knowing if this is sensible way to go without investigation of the data involved.

For example:

```
 gIsValid(gBuffer(p4, width = 0, byid = TRUE))
 [1] TRUE
```

Original answer follows:

END UPDATE

You may need a better tool to repair the geometry, or investigate the problems manually yourself. The `rgeos` package can be used to describe the existing problems, and you can visually identify where they occur - then edit them directly in R or go back to your GIS and do it there. Here's a simple example from the `gIsValid` function help:

```
library(rgeos)
p4 = readWKT("POLYGON ((0 40, 0 0, 40 40, 40 0, 0 40))")
gIsValid(p4, reason = TRUE)
[1] "Self-intersection[20 20]"
```

Change the `reason` return value for a more descriptive warning:

```
gIsValid(p4)
[1] FALSE
Warning message:
In RGEOSUnaryPredFunc(spgeom, byid, "rgeos_isvalid") :
  Self-intersection at or near point 20 20
```

So now plot the polygon and highlight the offending point:

```
plot(p4, col = "grey")
points(20, 20, pch = 3, cex = 3, col = "red")
axis(1);axis(2);box()
```

[image: Self-intersection polygon]

Since you are reading from shapefile, you can use the `byid` argument to test which polygons need investigation (though in this example they are all fine):

```
library(maptools)
xx <- readShapePoly(system.file("shapes/sids.shp", package="maptools")[1],
  IDvar="FIPSNO", proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=clrk66"))
gIsValid(xx, byid = TRUE)
37001 37003 37005 37007 37009 37011 
 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
...
```

Etc.